# Convert String to date in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a column which contains data but the problem is that this column has data type of varchar(50) and it has to be this due to some reasons,now what i want to do is while selecting data from table , i want to treat this column as date so that i can use it in where clause.  i am using the code below for converting it yo date , but it converts some values and then gives an error
this is my sample data

```
8/1/2002
6/9/2001
14/9/2001
26/7/2001
14/12/2001
21/1/2002
29/4/2001
7/5/2001
9/11/2001
16/7/2001


select CONVERT(date,sowingDate,103) from tblAgriculture_staging
```

I have tried which differnt version of date format e.g 103,105 etc

but still it converts some values but error comes on some values and query execution stops

Comment: What is the error you get? Which sql server version you are trying?

Comment: On what values does it fail? That would mean you have invalid date representations.

Comment: do you have 2 digit years anywhere in the data?

Comment: check my answer to examine your data

Comment: it will work on these dates 8/1/2002
6/9/2001

Comment: but it will not work on this date 
14/9/2001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
select case when isdate(sowingDate) = 1 then CONVERT(date,sowingDate,103) end [date] from tblAgriculture_staging
```

or (if you are using sql 2012)

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
select case when TRY_CONVERT(date, sowingDate) IS NOT NULL then CONVERT(date,sowingDate,103) end [date] from tblAgriculture_staging
```

but this solution hides (convert to NULL) all dates that are wrong. You can reverse the condition first and find/fix all rows with incorrect date (i.e. 31/02/2013) and then use this queries to show only valid dates

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bfb94/1)

Comment: `ISDATE('14/12/2001')` returns `0` while `CONVERT(date,'14/12/2001',103)` works just fine.

Comment: you can change this by defining SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

Comment: Fair enough, just add this to your answer and I will remove the downvote. You should also specify that the OP should probably find out the data error margin and try to fix the issues rather than coding for exceptions.

Comment: hi your answer is working but i want to know whether it will work for these dates dd/mm/yyyy, d/m/yyyy, dd/m/yyyy, d/m/yyyy ?

Comment: and please note that all dates are correct and are in format days/month/year

Comment: see link to SQLFiddle in the post... but nothing can stop you from testing it by yourself. It is very simple and you can answer to any questions by experimenting with queries

Answer (score 0):

> but it converts some values and then gives an error this is my sample
>   data

because some data are in invalid format or contains incorrect symbols.
Try this:

```
select CONVERT(date,ltrim(rtrim(sowingDate)), 103) from tblAgriculture_staging
```

or examine your values:

```
select ISDATE(sowingDate) as IsDate, sowingDate, CASE WHEN ISDATE(sowingDate)=1 THEN CONVERT(date,ltrim(rtrim(sowingDate)), 103) ELSE NULL END from tblAgriculture_staging
```

Comment: Bad day. My 4th answer with no response.

Comment: @user2539602 what does the last query return?

Answer (score 0):

This will return all the dates that are not actually dates.

```
select sowingDate from tblAgriculture_staging where isdate(sowingDate)=0
```

Comment: it is returning this date as false 14/9/2011

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly crappy, but so is storing dates as varchar.

this is code that has worked for me in the past where i had some dates with 4 digit years and some with 2 digit years.

```
 where  (TRY_CONVERT(Datetime2,LTRIM(RTRIM([INVC DTE])),1)>=@From
            AND TRY_CONVERT(Datetime2,LTRIM(RTRIM([INVC DTE])),1)<=@To)
        OR (TRY_CONVERT(Datetime2,LTRIM(RTRIM([INVC DTE])),101)>=@From
            AND TRY_CONVERT(Datetime2,LTRIM(RTRIM([INVC DTE])),101)<=@To)
```

SQL Server 2012 + Only

This assumes you have cleaned up anything that actually just isn't a date...

Comment: hi i have dates as dd/mm/yyyy or d/m/yyyy or d/mm/yyyy or dd/m/yyyy